# How to create the hadoop-0.21.0-core.jar using the source code?

Tags: hadoop

How to create the hadoop-0.21.0-core.jar using the source code?
I have check out the source code from svn. Now I have three dirs common,hdfs,mapred
I want to build the hadoop-0.21.0-core.jar to run a hadoop program..can you help me?

Comment: Why would you like to build it instead of downloading hadoop-0.21.0 directly and use it? (http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/hadoop/core/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply follow the instructions on the [Hadoop Wiki for developing using Eclipse](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment).